# How to use Timidity++ in android?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-ndk, midi

I have scenario where in I need to convert a .midi file to .wav file format in my android application,I googled a lot to find out that Timidity++ is the open source software that converts .midi to wav etc(but the source is in C)

So first of all can I use this to accomplish my task,If yes please suggest me how I can do that in android..like how to include the sofware into my android project.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: If you want to use that C code as part of your app you'll need the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Comment: Ya exactly,how do I need to include that source into my android Project..I have seen some examples of NDK...where in we need to add the static or shared C libs to JNI..How do I need to proceed with timidity++,Please advice.

Comment: Hi @amj did you finally find a solution this this ?

Comment: @Swapnil It was long back, but you should do it using the JNI and NDK implementation.

Comment: @amj I found a solution to what I was looking for using fluidsynth :). Thanks.